# How do I get R package versions to print in an R markdown beamer bibliography?

Tags: r, r-markdown, beamer, bibtex

I am linking to a `.bib` file in my header which looks like:

```
---
title: "Sample Document"
output: beamer_presentation
bibliography: bibliography.bib
---
```

I tried with and without a `.csl` file. Regardless, my `R` package citations are printed without the `R` package version information which is contained in the `BibTeX` note field.

How do I get these to print? It seems like overkill to try to hack `.csl` files.

**Update**

As an example, say I want to print the default citation returned from the `citation` command:

```
citation("scales")
```

> Hadley Wickham (2015). scales: Scale Functions for Visualization. R package
>     version 0.2.5. http://CRAN.R-project.org/package=scales

Answer (score 1):

The version number should be in the `version` field, not in the `note` field. The following `bibtex` entry

```
@Manual{rmanual,
  title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
  author = {{R Core Team}},
  organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
  address = {Vienna, Austria},
  year = {2015},
  url = {http://www.R-project.org/},
  version = {3.2.1}
}
```

prints as follows:

> R Core Team. 2015. R: A Language and Environment for Statistical
>   Computing (version 3.2.1). Vienna, Austria: R Foundation for
>   Statistical Computing. http://www.R-project.org/.

Comment: Why is that the default package citation puts them in the notes field then?       `citation("scales")`